# Can you tell whether an UDP packet is "younger" than another one?

Tags: sockets

What I mean is whether or not there is an algorithm which can make it possible to tell, when comparing two UDP packets, which one of them was sent first?

I would need to implement this in C# using libraries such as these: `System.Net.Sockets` and `System.Net`.

Also the answer to this question helps me build a reliable UDP protocol (that is the final goal I am trying to achieve, so if anyone knows a good optimized implementation of reliable UDP that would also solve my problem).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Sent first?** Not possible, unless the sender(s) are putting a timestamp, or a sequence number, in the application level packet payload.

Take a look at MoldUDP -- its a popular protocol in the financial sector for a single sender to reliably broadcast a data feed to many consumers.

Comment: Yeah I thought about putting a timestamp but it wouldn't work 100% theoretically. I need the app to be at least theoretically 100% reliable. Also I will check MoldUDP out, sounds like what I need thanks.

Comment: "*I thought about putting a timestamp but it wouldn't work 100% theoretically*" - why do you think that? Just use a timestamp that is not based on any particular timezone or locale. And use a data type that won't overflow in the near future. "*I need the app to be at least theoretically 100% reliable*" - then use an incrementing sequence number instead of a timestamp.

Comment: @RemyLebeau It wouldn't work 100% of the time because it is based on the clocks precision and for a very unlikely cases it won't work. Here I'll give you an example, say you open the client app very briefly it sends a "hello" message to the server app and then you open it again and it sends the same "hello" message again and they have the same timestamp because the clock is too imprecise to notice any difference, now I believe you can see that that could cause some problems.